# Flutter Dismissible doesn't get dismissed on startToEnd swipe

Tags: flutter

I am working on the app (simple ToDo list) and I ran into the weird behavior: Dismissible doesn't get dismissed (doesn't even register when I use the debug mode!) on startToEnd swipe. endToStart works just fine. Backgrounds and ConfirmDismiss works as expected.
I've checked the official docs and some free tutorials, my code doesn't work though I follow the instructions 'as is' at this point. Any ideas what can be wrong? I use the simple ListView.builder to make sure there are no other hand gestures events that can interfere, still doesn't work

Code:

```
class TaskListW extends StatefulWidget {
  TaskListW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TaskListW> createState() => _TaskListWState();
}
class _TaskListWState extends State<TaskListW> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List tasks = ['task', 'task1', 'task2'];

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, constraints) {
        return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  // shrinkWrap: true,
                  // physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: tasks.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return Dismissible(
                      child: TaskItem("1231241242", "DummyTask", "Social"),
                      key: ValueKey(tasks[index]),
                      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Row(
                            children: const [
                              Text(
                                'Done',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      secondaryBackground: Container(
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: const [
                              Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                        if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                          print('Marked Completed');
                        } else {
                          print('Removed item');
                        }

                        setState(() {
                          tasks.removeAt(index);
                        });
                      },
                      confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
                        if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text("Well Done!"),
                                );
                              });
                        } else {
                          return await showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: const Text("Delete Confirmation"),
                                content: const Text(
                                    "Are you sure you want to delete this item?"),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                      },
                                      child: const Text("Delete")),
                                  TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                                    child: const Text("Cancel"),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }
                        ;
                        return null;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ]);
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a proper boolean ("true" in your case) from your `confirmDismiss` method, like so:

```
confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
              if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                 await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Well Done!"),
                      );
                    });
                    return true;
              } else {...
```

From the widget's `confirmDismiss` method docs:

> If the returned Future completes true, then this widget will be dismissed, otherwise it will be moved back to its original location.

Hope that helps